# Prime gaps and gaps between successive critical zeros of zeta

Tags: number-theory, fourier-transform, riemann-zeta, prime-gaps

Assuming RH, the sequence of critical zeros of the Riemann zeta function can be viewed as the Fourier transform of the sequence of primes. From a physicist point of view, the average gap between the elements of a sequence of points on a straight line is the reciprocal of the average gap of the sequence obtained through the application of the Fourier transform, up to a normalisation factor of  $ 2\pi $.
Is there thus a heuristics suggesting that the proportion of integers n below x such that  $a\leq\dfrac{p_{n+1}-p_{n}}{\log p_{n}} \leq b$ is equal to the proportion of critical Riemann zeros  $ 1/2+i\gamma_{n} $ of imaginary part less than T such that  $\dfrac{2\pi}{b}\leq (\gamma_{n+1}-\gamma_{n})\log\gamma_{n}\leq\dfrac{2\pi}{a} $ with  $ 0\lt a\lt b\lt\infty $?

Comment: I get the parallel between the zeros and the primes I think but I don't get why "Assuming RH, the sequence of critical zeros of the Riemann zeta function can be viewed as the Fourier transform of the sequence of primes" could you further explain it please, thanks

Comment: This idea goes back to Riemann himself, but I wouldn't be able to expose it rigorously. I used to study physics and find it difficult to keep up with the level of rigor of genuine mathematicians.

Comment: the level of rigor of genuine mathematicians is just beyond me also, was just curious if what you wrote could mean that one can obtain the zero counting function $N(T)$ function as a Fourier transform of the prime counting function $\pi(x)$ or some other kind of connection

Comment: Very informally, the non trivial zeros of zeta, and gaps thereof, on one hand, and the primes and gaps thereof on the other hand appear as dual to each other. If you know Heisenberg principle, you can see them as conjugate variables like the pair (Energy, time).

Comment: Here the factor $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ plays an analogous role to the reduced Planck constant.

Comment: I also expect the real part of the non trivial zeros to be the manifestation of a similar Fourier duality between them and the trivial ones, the behavior of zeta in the critical strip being determined by its behavior outside of it.

Comment: My wikipedia physics tells me that $\operatorname{Tr}(\mathrm{e}^{-tH}) = \sum_n \mathrm{e}^{-tE_n}$ and that by Hilbert-Poyla conjecture one should identify the zeros with Eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian so $E_n=\frac{1}{2}+\gamma_j$, but how one should relate time $t$ with the primes $p_n$? and how should one relate it with the uncertainty principle $\frac{\hbar}{2} \leq ( \langle E^2 \rangle - \langle E \rangle^2)( \langle t^2 \rangle - \langle t \rangle^2)=\sigma_{E}\sigma_{T}$ but what would it mean $\sigma_p\sigma_{\gamma}$?